# InvalidOperationException: An operation is already in progress

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, razorengine

I am using Asp.net core Razor engine Entity Framework.  I keep getting the error above and it from what I have read, it refers to the the db already being used for an operation.  I am not sure why this would be happening. Is is because it is in a foreach loop?  What would the workaround be?  Here is my code

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("currentSession")]
public IActionResult CurrentSession()
{

    var id = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("Id");
    if(id != null)
    {
        var user = _context.User.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
         ViewBag.User = user;
         ViewBag.User_Id = id;
         ViewBag.Auction = _context.Auction.AsEnumerable();
         foreach(var item in ViewBag.Auction)
         {
             if(item.End_Date < DateTime.Now)
             {
                 var seller_id = (int)item.Id_Of_Seller;
                 var seller = _context.User.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == seller_id); //this is the line that causes the error in the title
                 var bidder_id = (int)item.Id_Highest_Bid;
                 var buyer = _context.User.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == bidder_id); //this line also causes the same error
                 buyer.Wallet -= item.Bid;
                 seller.Wallet += item.Bid;

                _context.Auction.Remove(item);
                _context.SaveChanges();
             }
         }
         return View("Home");
    } 
    return RedirectToAction("LoginPage");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try replacing AsEnumerable with ToList?

```
         ViewBag.Auction = _context.Auction.ToList();
```

Comment: Because enumerables doesn't load all data in memory but fetches data from DB as you enumerate through them via _context and inside the loop you were using _context again to Remove data on same Entity which is being enumerated. Calling .ToList() loads copy of the Auction data in first place and so _context have only single operation to perform on Auction entity i.e. Remove.

Comment: AsEnumerable is a deferred action and you are performing something again on the db context in that step. That is the reason you encountered that error.

Comment: This is not a good answer as it only hides the underlying issue.  As an example, what if there are a million records, loading them all into memory before you can do anything with them.
What it you are doing this as a Task, and whilst this task is processing, another task needs to perform something on the context?
The AddDbContext we need to use for dependency injection does not work in my opinion as there are many such scenarios where multiple background processes all need data from the data store.
I don't have an answer to this issue though hence my searching issues with this error.

Answer (score 1):

I added `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` to my sql server connection strings and this fixed the exception.  No other changes were needed.

This fixed the async methods, the background tasks and IQueryable loops for me.